# How to add staging and production environment using gitlab and digitalocean's server

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci

I'm setting production environment for a project and i need to create two environments, one for staging(testing) and one for production.
How can I do this using gitlab's CI and digitalocean's server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DigitalOcean's server will the environment target or that's will be gitlab-runner hosts?

First you need to install at least one gitlab-runner (or use shared runners).

Use "only" to define the build (and deploy source branch) and use tags in assign build job to specified gitlab-runners

Comment: can  you show me some code about it or give some links to tutorial to see how to use it.